# Spreecommerce promotion "User" rule creating adjustments for all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a rails/spree store application that has a long running promotion with [spree's "User" rule](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-3-stable/core/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb). The issue is that while the promotion is active, an ineligible adjustment is created for every order in the store that the promotion **does not** apply to. This is adding significant bloat in the database and slowing down checkout.

Strangely, other promotions with similarly restrictive rules don't do this. How can I modify the rule or otherwise, in order to stop the creation of ineligible adjustments for all orders?

Comment: Is this promotion using any other rules? Is the ineligible adjustment visible to the user?

Comment: Hi Uri, the promotion is not using any other rules. The adjustment isn't visible to the user ( because it's ineligible, there adjustment has no consequence).

Comment: What calculator did you attach? I took a look at the adjustments action and  I cant see why it would create an adjustment unless the amount is non 0, which would imply that the calculator is doing something weird...

Comment: @UriMikhli The calculator is a Spree::Calculator::FlatPercentItemTotal. Shouldn't it first check eligibility before doing anything with the adjustment action though?

Comment: Try stepping through and seeing if eligible? was ever equal true... looking at the eligible? method in https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-3-stable/core/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb  I have a suspicion that maybe at first the 'users' in line 17 (users.include?(order.user)) is actually the list of all users rather then what 'spree_promotion_rules_users' defines are the eligible users.

Comment: @UriMikhli Thanks for your continued help. I tried stepping through it and 'users' is never all users, it stays what spree_promotion_rules_users defines it to be.

Comment: An adjustment is being created and there is evidence that eligible? is false... that leads me to believe there is a use case where the action is not respecting the eligible? I'm going to try this promotion/rule combo on my home spree project over the weekend and report back to you next week... sorry I couldnt be of more help. You could try to delete the promotion and recreate it. I've seen that work in older versions of spree, when promotions behave weird.

Comment: @UriMikhli No worries. I tried creating a fresh promotion with the same rule / action combo and I'm seeing the same behavior. Something I did notice though was that if I change the action to "create per-line-item adjustment" with a PercentOnLineItem calculator, it accomplishes the same thing without the extraneous adjustments! So I'll probably just go with that unless you find something.

Comment: Check that, "create per-line-item adjustment" action won't work in my case for bookkeeping reasons. So I need to fix spree's "create whole order adjustment" action. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting thing that happened(read... another bug), is that if a different promotion with an order level adjustment is eligible it creats an eligible adjustment (as it should), but the total for that adjustment includes the total from the ineligible adjustment... this is probably a separate bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding an `eligible?` check to the [`perform` method](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-3-stable/core/app/models/spree/promotion/actions/create_adjustment.rb#L20) of the `CreateAdjustment` promotion action.

```
def perform(options = {})
  order = options[:order]
  return if promotion_credit_exists?(order)
  return if !eligible?(order)

  amount = compute_amount(order)
  Spree::Adjustment.create!(
    amount: amount, 
    order: order,
    adjustable: order,
    source: self,
    label: "#{Spree.t(:promotion)} (#{promotion.name})"
  )       
  true    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a function in the an order decorator which fires on the transition to complete. make it delete all adjustments which are ineligible

```
#app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb

module Spree
  Order.class_eval do
    state_machine do
      after_transition :to => :complete do |order|
        order.delete_ineligible_adjustments
      end
    end

    def delete_ineligible_adjustments
      self.adjustments.promotion.where(eligible: false).destroy_all
    end
  end
end
```